# MariaDB HAProxy deadlock

Tags: mariadb, deadlock, haproxy, zabbix, keep-alive

I'm trying to run Zabbix with haproxy, keepalived, mariadb and galera cluster. Can you help me?

- 3 mariadb cluster databse server.
- 2 keepalived and haproxy server.
- 1 zabbix server.

log:

```
Error in query [COMMIT] [Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction]
```

log2:

```
Sep 28 13:59:41 db2 mysqld[18273]: 2020-09-28 13:59:41 101 [Warning] Aborted connection 101 to db: 'mydb' user: 'myuser' host: '192.168.1.107' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

log3:

```
Sep 28 14:01:58 hake haproxy[16785]: 192.168.1.103:37036 [28/Sep/2020:14:01:58.229] galera_cluster_frontend galera_cluster_backend/db2 1/1/8 295 -- 14/14/13/4/0 0/0
Sep 28 14:01:59 hake haproxy[16785]: 192.168.1.103:36960 [28/Sep/2020:14:01:09.283] galera_cluster_frontend galera_cluster_backend/db1 1/0/50008 364 cD 13/13/12/4/0 0/0
Sep 28 14:01:59 hake haproxy[16785]: 192.168.1.103:37038 [28/Sep/2020:14:01:59.492] galera_cluster_frontend galera_cluster_backend/db3 1/0/27 2550 -- 14/14/13/4/0 0/0
```

log4:

```
Sep 28 14:05:29 hake Keepalived_vrrp[19536]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Sep 28 14:05:29 hake Keepalived_vrrp[19536]: WARNING - default user 'keepalived_script' for script execution does not exist - please create.
Sep 28 14:05:29 hake Keepalived_vrrp[19536]: Truncating auth_pass to 8 characters
Sep 28 14:05:29 hake Keepalived_vrrp[19536]: SECURITY VIOLATION - scripts are being executed but script_security not enabled.
Sep 28 14:05:29 hake Keepalived_vrrp[19536]: Using LinkWatch kernel netlink reflector...
Sep 28 14:05:29 hake Keepalived_vrrp[19536]: VRRP_Script(chk_haproxy) succeeded
Sep 28 14:05:30 hake Keepalived_vrrp[19536]: VRRP_Instance(LB_VIP) Transition to MASTER STATE
Sep 28 14:05:30 hake Keepalived_vrrp[19536]: VRRP_Instance(LB_VIP) Changing effective priority from 101 to 103
Sep 28 14:05:31 hake Keepalived_vrrp[19536]: VRRP_Instance(LB_VIP) Entering MASTER STATE
Sep 28 14:05:31 hake Keepalived_vrrp[19536]: SMTP connection ERROR to [127.0.0.1]:25.
```

Answer (score 0):

The HAProxy log gives you a hint:

```
Sep 28 14:01:59 hake haproxy[16785]: 192.168.1.103:36960 [28/Sep/2020:14:01:09.283] galera_cluster_frontend galera_cluster_backend/db1 1/0/50008 364 cD 13/13/12/4/0 0/0
```

As you can see, the [session state at disconnect](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#8.5) is given as `cD`. This means, to quote the linked docs:

> The client did not send nor acknowledge any data for as long as the
> "timeout client" delay. This is often caused by network failures on
> the client side, or the client simply leaving the net uncleanly.

As such, either your client has actually gone away, or some network changes have occurred between your MySQL client and HAProxy, or (rather more probable): you have set a `timeout client` setting in HAProxy which is too short.

In that case, you might be able to increase this timeout to ensure that existing connections are held open for a longer time. You should however make sure to not make this timeout too long either to still ensure that actually broken or uncleanly aborted connections are eventually detected and recycled.

Especially with TCP mode, It is generally good practice to set the `timeout client` and `timeout server` to the same values.

Comment: I previously increased the timeout. but as soon as the timeout expires i lose connection